# Replace line breaks between CDATA section in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a csv file where one of the column includes a CDATA section. There are few line breaks within the CDATA section content which is causing an issue when I am trying to import the data in excel. I was trying to use regex expression below to remove the line breaks using Notepad++ but it does not seem to be working.

regex
`(<!\[CDATA\[|\G(?!\A))((?!\]\]>).)*?\K((\n))`

I was trying to replace in Notepad++ using capture group `\2`

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notepad++ is known for having a bug in which `\A` doesn't match at the right position. Moreover, you don't need capturing groups.

To workaround `\A` bug we are going to use `(?!^(?<![\s\S]))` instead of `\A`.

- `^(?<![\s\S])` means match at start of a line only when it is not preceded by a character (somehow simulating `\A`).

Regex:

```
(?:<!\[CDATA\[|\G(?!^(?<![\s\S]))).*\K\R
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/Il98Qf/1)

Note: `(?<![\s\S])` could be replaced with `(?<!\C)` here.

Comment: The regex works but it also removes the line breaks in the lines below the CDATA end tag ']]>' [Updated Example](https://regex101.com/r/Il98Qf/1)

Comment: Yes, right. Put `(?!.*]]>)` before `.*`. See it in action https://regex101.com/r/Il98Qf/3 or use [**`(?:<!\[CDATA\[|\G(?!^(?<![\s\S])))(?:(?!]]>).)*\K\R`**](https://regex101.com/r/Il98Qf/4)

Comment: How to also remove comma character along with line break?

Comment: @user320587 Please create a fiddle.